# Loading asynchronously in a UserControl WPF with MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, execute

I have a small problem async loader in a view with WPF MVVM pattern .
I wish that when I click the button Read from UserControl View , send a Command to view model , and then it was off a loading before making execute and it disappeared when I return data .
The data is read by a machine via optical USB .
All works , the program runs perfectly, just can not bring up the loading so async . The loading is displayed along with the return of reading , because synchronous . How can I do asynchronous ? I tried it with the task but it seems he does not consider the code .

```
class  ReadAndPrintFromDevice : ICommand
    {
        async Task<int> showLoader()
        {
           model.ShowLoader = true;                         
           return 1;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {                    
            return true;
        }

        public async void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            showLoader async here
            //other code..
            showloader async shadow here, after other code
        }
    }
```

if you need more information tell in the comments that I add all .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
public class ReadAndPrintFromDeviceAsyncCommand : PropertyChangedBase, ICommand
{
    private bool _IsBusy;

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return _IsBusy; }
        private set
        {
            _IsBusy = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return !IsBusy;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public async void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        await ...

        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

By using an `IsBusy` property, you can simply set that to be `true` before executing the asynchronous operation, and once it's done, set it back to false.

You can then bind your control to the `IsBusy` property:

```
<MyControl Visibility="{Binding SomeCommand.IsBusy, ...}"
```

The above example would require a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` to work, but I think you get the idea.

Also, the command uses a `PropertyChangedBase` which I have created to simply make implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` a bit easier, the code for this class is here:

```
public abstract class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyOfPropertyChange([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```